# Assets\Footsteps.cs(5,20): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces

seeking help regarding a problem I'm facing while creating a footsteps script for Unity.
I pasted this code (in C#) off some manual/guide on how to setup footstep sounds but when I save it and go back to Unity an error occurs, saying something like this:

*Assets\Footsteps.cs(5,20): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods*

- I'm using Unity 2019.4.17f1.
- I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Code 2019.
- The code was from https://coding.degree/unity-audio-tutorial/#Footstep_Sounds

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public AudioClip[] footstepClips;
public AudioSource audioSource;

public float footstepThreshold;
public float footstepRate;
private float lastFootstepTime;

public CharacterController controller;

void Update ()
{
    if(controller.velocity.magnitude > footstepThreshold)
    {
        if(Time.time - lastFootstepTime > footstepRate)
        {
            lastFootstepTime = Time.time;
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(footstepClips[Random.Range(0, footstepClips.Length)]);
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, I think the code that I obtained from the coding degree website was outdated. Also if there were any grammatical mistakes in this thread that's because I made this during night time, sorry if you concluded that as a mistake.

Comment: Someone help me please

Comment: You need to wrap all that inside a **class** .. that's basic c#

Comment: Your class should be `public class Footstep : MonoBehaviour { ... }` since for components the script name has to match the class name in order to work correctly in Unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't contained in a class. When you create a C# script in unity it automatically has the class declaration for you to put your code in along with the start and update functions.

You need to add the line `public class Footstep : MonoBehaviour {`  underneath the using statements and above the first variable declaration. Don't forget to add a closing curly brace to the end of the file `}`

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class Footstep : MonoBehaviour {
    
       public AudioClip[] footstepClips;
       public AudioSource audioSource;
    
       public float footstepThreshold;
       public float footstepRate;
       private float lastFootstepTime;
    
       public CharacterController controller;
    
       void Update ()
       {
           if(controller.velocity.magnitude > footstepThreshold)
           {
               if(Time.time - lastFootstepTime > footstepRate)
               {
                   lastFootstepTime = Time.time;
                   audioSource.PlayOneShot(footstepClips[Random.Range(0, footstepClips.Length)]);
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you change `PlayerController` to `Footstep` since otherwise OP will directly have the next issue for the component not being found by Unity ;) The script and class name have to match exactly and OP's script is called `Footstep.cs` (see error in question)

Comment: Thanks! I updated. I went and looked at the tutorial and that part of the question on here totally slipped my mind.